# Does Resharper recognize std::make_unique in a hard-code way?

Tags: c++, resharper, c++14, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

If I code :-

```
class B;  //some B.h has definition of B
std::make_unique<B>();
```

Resharper will warn me that I should include `B.h`. (correct)

> Type 'B' is incomplete

However, if I try to mimic code of `std::unique_ptr<T>` and put it inside `Test.h`:-

**Test.h**

```
//inside class Test
template<class _Ty,
class... _Types> inline
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<_Ty>::value,
    std::unique_ptr<_Ty> >::type test2(_Types&&... _Args)
{   // make a unique_ptr
return (std::unique_ptr<_Ty>(new _Ty( std::forward<_Types>(_Args)...)));
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Test.h"
//inside some function
test2<B>();
```

I will not get any warning. (but it is uncompilable because B is incomplete.)

**Question**

- Does **Resharper** hardcode the checking around `std::make_unique`?
- If not, how to code in a way that makes Resharper correctly recommend? (should include `B.h`)
  In the real usage, I am trying to create some custom smart pointer + pool,
  and I want Reshaper to correctly recommend `#include` in the user's file.

It also occurs to `std::make_shared`.

**Edit:-**

As Igor Akhmetov mentioned that it was hardcoded, is there anyway I can clue Resharper? e.g. :-

```
//Hey, Resharper, the user must include full definition of "T".
//    Resharper, forward declaration is not enough for "T".
template<class T> T* f(){
    return new T();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, completeness and overload resolution checks are hardcoded for `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`. For functions like `std::make_unique`, R++ can't deduce from function's signature that definition of the class used as a template argument is needed. However, `std::make_unique` and `std::make_unique` are so common, that additional checks were introduced specifically for them.

That said, definitions of classes used as template arguments are usually required for template function parameters that are forwarding references. We might consider showing a warning (but not an error) in this case.

Comment: Thank!  It is a bit disappointing though, but I can understand how hard it is to implement this feature.   ..... By the way, is there any way to clue Resharper? (I have edited the question.)

Comment: There's no way to do that at the moment. The natural approach would be to have a special attribute, but it looks like attributes can not be applied to template parameters in C++. I filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-19172, we'll see if we can come up with some way of doing that.

Comment: I have another question about Resharper C++ auto-complete feature.  Not sure Resharper can do it.   I would be appreciated if you  can take a look.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164856/autocompletion-of-parameter-list-static-fields-without-typing-a-classname