# autocompletion of parameter : list static fields without typing a ClassName::

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, parameters, autocomplete, resharper

How to make auto-completion list all (static) fields of a certain class that has appropriate variable-type when <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd> at a slot of parameter in a certain function?

## Example

**I tried to <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd> in the below code :-**

[image]

<sub>(Code as text is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b42ff0f9409851aa).)</sub>

**Question:** How to make it show `E_1` `E_2` `E_3`?
I don't mind another plugin if I really need one.

**It currently works but only for enum :-**

[image]

## My workaround

In practice, to get smart clue, I have to **type more** (`PrototypeList::`) :-

[image]

### Bounty Reason

Here is the result of the current answer (*citizenmatt*'s):-

[image]

It is different, but still not show `E_1` `E_2` `E_3`.

Comment: Why don't you use a namespace for that?

Comment: @Chris Tsiakoulas   It is my preference.  I don't believe using namespace has any major advantage either.  By the way, using namespace doesn't help about auto completion at all. (just test - `PrototypeList` is a namespace in the test)

Comment: I remember using namespaces in the beginning of our code in c++ to avoid writing stuff later, like "using namespace std;" so we wouldn't have to write std::cin etc. all the time. We just wrote cin after that...

Comment: @Chris Tsiakoulas   Thank.   Ok, you win.  XD  ..... Yes, it is a bit better.  Now, I still have to manually type `using namespace PrototypeList;` (in every related user function) and I will get the cute auto-completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, ReSharper does help you here. All of `E_1`, `E_2` and `E_3` are in the completion list, but not on the top of it - they are assigned lower scores because they need an additional qualifier. That said, looks like there is still an issue with scoring:
[image]

`E_2` and `E_3` are in the list too, but they are not shown alongside `E_1`. We'll investigate this ([RSCPP-19501](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-19501)).

Comment: Thank a lot!  I have another question about Resharper C++ content-assist  feature. Not sure if it is beyond Resharper ability. I would be appreciated if you may take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093393/content-assist-clue-of-type-of-a-function-that-has-parameter-type-depend-on-u

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Smart Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Smart.html)? This feature will only show completion items that are valid for the current context. I think it works in C++, too.