# Content assist : clue of type of a function that has parameter type depend on "using" inside T

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, resharper, content-assist, visual-assist

How to make Visual Studio show a completely-deduced content-assist for a function that  has type depends on alias of a `T`?

### Example

`b.f` in the example can't give me a completely-deduced content-assist.
It should clue `int`, not `SomeClass::A<int>::AT`.

```
class SomeClass{
    template<class T>class A{public: using AT=T;};
    template<class AX>class B{public: void f( typename AX::AT){}};
    template<class AX,class X>class C{public: void f( typename X){}};
    public: void test(){
        B<A<int>> b;     b.f(
    }
};
```

**Testing `b.f()` :-**

[image]

### Poor Workaround

I have to refactor `B<A<int>>` to `C<A<int>,`**`int`**`>`.

```
template<class T>class A{public: using AT=T;};
template<class AX,class X>class C{public: void f( typename X){}};
public: void test(){
    C<A<int>,int> c;  c.f(
}
```

**Testing `c.f()` :-**

[image]

I may rely on content-assist too much, but it greatly helps a newbie like me.

Comment: ReSharper C++ at the moment only shows expansions of template parameters when a template function is called. We'll consider expanding this feature to cover your use case and will also show expansions of typedefs/type aliases in the function type. You can follow [RSCPP-19656](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-19656), thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Igor Akhmetov Thank a lot!   I have another new question specifically about macro in resharper-c++.    I would be really glad if you may take a look!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149003/resharper-subtituate-macro-with-multi-line-code