# Resharper : subtituate macro with multi-line code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper, resharper-c++

Is it possible to make Resharper **Substituate macro call** in separate-lines mode?

### Example

I have this code :-

```
#define TEST(T) int T=5;  \
T++;

TEST(apple);
```

If I click
**Substituate macro call and all nested calls**   like this :-

[image]

The line `TEST(apple);` will become  :-

```
int apple=5; apple++;;
```

I hope there is an option to make the result be 2 separate lines :-

```
int apple=5; 
apple++;;
```

### **Other notes**

I know that macro with `\` is finally interpreted as a single line,
but it would be nice if there is an option to show it as many lines for eye-candy.
(Even it may break the macro behavior, e.g. those with `__LINE__` )

It would be useful for debugging for a 10+ lines macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, but you can always select the resulting code after a macro substitution and invoke "Reformat Code" (`Ctrl+Alt+Enter`) to make it readable.

Comment: Hi, I want to know about Resharper's feature related to dependent name highlighting (template function).   I would be glad if you take a look :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900697/red-squiggle-non-existing-dependent-name-e-g-ctnonmember-as-error   Thanks as always!

Comment: @javaLover Thanks for pinging me, I've added a comment to the question.

Comment: I am the person to say thank.  ( I am still using this `ctrl+alt+enter` every month for Macro.)  XD

Comment: Hi, I am trying CLion, do you happen to how to import Visual Studio project to CLion?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577196/import-visual-studios-filter-of-a-project-to-clion     Thank.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know about Resharper's feature related to search-everywhere (ctrl+T).  I would be glad if you may take a look.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64190402/resharper-c-search-everywhere-doesnt-detect-word-when-words-order-are-sw    Thanks!