# red-squiggle non-existing dependent name (e.g. C<T>::nonMember ) as error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, resharper

How to make Resharper syntax-highlight non-exist dependent name (e.g. member field) as error?

In the below code, I expect `a.nonMember` to has red squiggle.

```
template<class T>class Test1{
    public: int member;
};
template<class T>void f(){
    Test1<T> a;
    a.member=5;
    a.nonMember=8;    //<-- expect red squiggle here
}
```

However, there is no such red squiggle.

I believe there must be such a feature,
 because Resharper can already recognize all fields of `Test1<>` correctly (shown in the following image).

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  I agree that it would be useful if Resharper shows that field as "hint-level" warning.

Comment: The R++ team will consider an inspection like this but so far we are not sure what would be a good way to implement it. This works in completion because we can create a fake instantiation of a single class, but doing this from code analysis for all classes in the file could potentially be slow.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper is not wrong. It has no way to know such a member doesn't exist, because the member is dependent, and so *could* exist.

```
template<>
class Test1<int> {
    public: int nonMember;
};
```

What should be highlighted now when we can call `f<int>()`? The possibility of specializations means that making such diagnostics is intractable for dependent names.

Comment: Good point.  Thanks.   Do you happen to know a way to suggest Resharper that a template class has no specialization?

Comment: @cppBeginner - I don't know of such an option.