# Import hierarchy of Visual Studio project to CLion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clion

I want to import many (100+ file) VS projects to CLion.
My main difficulty is to import all **Filter** information.

Here is an example.  I have a `projectTest`.
The project contains `NewFilter1\NewFilter2\lalala.cpp`.

[image]

Filter in VS is like a virtual directory.
The `lalala.cpp` is still in project directory e.g. `C:\projectTest`, not `C:\NewFilter1\NewFilter2`.
The filter information is stored in `*.filter` as.

```
<Filter Include="NewFilter1\NewFilter2">
<UniqueIdentifier>{147f0a04-1541-be34-301a-5810a0d02301}</UniqueIdentifier</Filter> 
...
<ClCompile Include="lalala.cpp"> <Filter>NewFilter1\NewFilter2</Filter> </ClCompile>
```

How to import this information to CLion?

Comment: There's unfortunately no direct way to import a VS project into CLion. The first step might be to move your project to using CMake. C++ support is also coming soon to Rider (the standalone IDE from JetBrains for .NET and MSBuild-based projects), so you'll be able to open a C++ VS project from Rider.

Comment: @Igor Akhmetov Thank a lot, Igor. :)

Comment: @IgorAkhmetov: Can Rider open VS project now?

Comment: @Rainning No, but you can try the free [Rider for Unreal Engine](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/rider-unreal/) preview which should work fine for general-purpose MSBuild-based C++ projects.

Comment: @IgorAkhmetov: I'm happy to see your helpful reply~ Sounds a good alternative! (I was thinking about using VS to re-create my project in CMake to achieve this.)