# Resharper C++ : Search-Everywhere doesn't detect "CatDog", when search for "dog cat"

Tags: c++, resharper

I have 3 classes : `CatDog`, `Cat_Dog` and `CatEatDog`.
If I `ctrl+T` for `dog cat`, Resharper C++ will not find any of the class.

[image]

How to modify setting to make Resharper shows all class/function that contains both words (all of 3 classes in this case) when search for `dog cat`?

Another experiment : If I `ctrl+T` for just `dog`, Resharper will correctly show all of them.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this with 2020.2. Which version of R++ are you using?

Comment: @Igor  :: Thanks.   I use Resharper C++ 2020.2.1 in Visual Studio 2019,  does it shows all 3 classes in your test (me none)?

Comment: Yes, it shows all three, not sure why it doesn't work in your project. Please also try a camel-hump version of the search query "DogCat", it should definitely work.

Comment: @Igor :: Thank a lot!  "DogCat" works.  It is the answer!